# Invoice Group created without Invoices

Tags: mapreduce, grouping, netsuite, suitescript2.0, invoice

I am trying to create a group invoice using a map reduce script, based on Subscription IDs.When I execute the script, a group invoice is created, but no invoices are linked to it. There are no errors on the script. The sublist contains no invocies. Can you please help?
Attached below is the reduce part of the script :

const reduce = (reduceContext) => {

```
      var invGrpID ;
      var custName;
      var custTerms;
      var subscriptionID = reduceContext.key;
      var invValues = reduceContext.values;
      log.debug({title: 'subscriptionID ' ,details:  subscriptionID });
      log.debug({title: 'invValues' ,details:  invValues});           


        //Subscription Details
       var param_SubscriptionSrch = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name:'custscript_subscription_dtls'});
       var SubscriptionSearch = search.load({
        id: param_SubscriptionSrch
        })           
       var aFilters = [];
       aFilters.push(
           search.createFilter({
               name    : 'internalid',
               operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
               values  : subscriptionKey
           })
       ); 
       
     
         var newSearch = search.create({
            type: 'CUSTOMRECORD_SUBSCRIPTION',
            filters: aFilters,
            columns: SubscriptionSearch.columns
        }); 
        
        var aResults = newSearch.run();
        var results = aResults.getRange({
            start: 0,
            end: 5
        });
       
        for(var x=0; x < results.length; x++){
            custName  = results[x].getValue(aResults.columns[0]);
            custTerms = results[x].getValue(aResults.columns[1]);
        }
        log.debug({title: 'a Results' ,details:  custName+', '+custTerms}); 

       var invGrpRec  = record.create({
        type:'invoicegroup'
       })
       invGrpRec.setValue({fieldId: 'customer',value: custName,ignoreFieldChange: true});           
       invGrpRec.setValue({fieldId: 'terms',value: custTerms,ignoreFieldChange: true});           
       var grpInvoicId = invGrpRec.save({enableSourcing: true,ignoreMandatoryFields: true});
       
       actionMod.execute({recordType: 'invoicegroup',id: 'groupinvoices',params: {recordId: grpInvoicId,invoicelist: invValues}});
       //actionMod.execute({recordType: 'invoicegroup',id: 'groupinvoices',params: {recordId: grpInvoicId,invoicelist: '14795831,14803649'}});
       //log.debug({title: 'grpInvID' ,details: grpInvID}); 
      
    }
```

Invoice values are given as : invValues : ["14795831","14803649"]